# Dependency injection implementation for app setting c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

`NotificationHubConnectionSettings.cs` file to fetch connection string from web.config

```
  public class NotificationHubConnectionSettings
    {
        public NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }
        public NotificationHubConnectionSettings()
        {
            Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.ConnectionString"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHub"]);
        }
    }
```

Inside `Bootstrapper.cs` 
using Unity dependency injection nuget

```
  private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            try
            {
                var container = new UnityContainer();

                container.RegisterType<NotificationHubConnectionSettings>().RegisterType<NotificationHubConnectionSettings>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

                return container;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

In `HomeController.cs`

want to implement dependency injection -

```
  private readonly NotificationHubClient _hub;

        public HomeController(NotificationHubConnectionSettings hub)
        {
            _hub = hub.Hub;
        }

        // POST api/register
        // This creates a registration id
        public async Task<string> Post(string handle = null)
        {
            string newRegistrationId = null;

            if (handle != null)
            {
                var registrations = await _hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle, 100);
```

Is this correct way to implement dependency injection?

Comment: This is a code review question. which is off topic for this site. Is there some error/issue that is being experienced?

Comment: It does not look right to me, but I don't know much about Unity as a container. You should be binding an interface to a concrete type in your container code.container.RegisterType<INotificationHubConnectionSettings>().RegisterType<NotificationHubConnectionSettings>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())

Then you should be taking that interface as your constructor parameter type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a interface type here.

Create a contract for INotificationHubConnectionSettings class in the form of a interface which dictates to your system all public methods and properties available.

```
    public interface INotificationHubConnectionSettings
    {
        NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }
    }
```

Then have your actual NotificationHubConnectionSettings class inherit from this interface;

```
    public class NotificationHubConnectionSettings : INotificationHubConnectionSettings
    {
        public NotificationHubClient Hub { get; set; }
        public NotificationHubConnectionSettings()
        {
            Hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.ConnectionString"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationHub"]);
        }
    }
```

Now register the interface and class inside of UnityContainer and change your constructor to the following;

```
    private readonly INotificationHubClient _hub;
    public HomeController(NotificationHubConnectionSettings hub)
    {
        _hub = hub.Hub;
    }
```

Always use interfaces for dependency injection.

Comment: we do not have interface `INotificationHubClient `

Comment: we can do like this
`  private readonly NotificationHubClient _hub;

        public BuildingAlertController(INotificationHubConnectionSettings hub)
        {
            _hub = hub.Hub;
        }`